# Swipe to refresh layout not working with linear layout manager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, material-design, swiperefreshlayout

I have a RecyclerView working as expected , I tried to add a swipe to refresh layout to it as below :

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/srl_contacts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/senderContainer"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_connection_status">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_chat_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

the RecyclerView worked fine ,but there was no swipe to refresh , then i commented  the line where i set the linear layout manager to the RecyclerView  and the swipe to refresh implementation worked and `OnRefresh()` interface was called

in java :

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRvList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);  // <----- i commented this , and every thing worked fine , there was no data shown of course.
```

could be the problem with the adapter? I removed every line where i set an adapter to the RecyclerView ,and problem stayed ,only when i don't set the linear layout manager the swipe to refresh works .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some more debugging it turns out the problem is the RecyclerView elements ,  the first element of the the list was hidden (Visibility.gone)  so every time the list reach the top list the linearLayoutManger was trying to get the first Visible  element which is not presented so the swipe to refresh animation was never called .

Answer (score 1):

Constructor used when layout manager is set in XML by RecyclerView attribute `"layoutManager"`.

since you didn't used that with in xml, i suggest to remove constructor also remove **LinearLayoutManager** because it's requiered constructor, and replace with **StaggeredGridLayoutManager** without passing constructor like :

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager sglm =
                new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(columnCount, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRvList.setLayoutManager(sglm);
```

**OR** You can set the `layououtManger` in your `recycleView`  XML for your case layoutManager is Linear:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_chat_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    android:scrollbars="none"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

now you can pass constructor like you used :

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
```

Comment: tried both ways and failed to produce swipe to refresh , but worked of course for shown the data .

Comment: @Ahmedna you should `mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);` first

Comment: kinda of a break through , the swipe to refresh animation is now always 
showing ,but it is not called when actual swiping to refresh occur , this behavior is very strange to me , never faced it with a swiperefreshlayout